# #REDIRECT pages showing in MediaWiki search

Tags: mediawiki

I have several pages on a MediaWiki installation that use redirects. According to [the MediaWiki Redirect documentation](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Redirects):

> After making a redirect at a page, you can no longer get to that page by using its name or by any link using that name; **and they do not show up in wiki search results**, either.

However, all my redirects are showing in search results:

[image: Search results]

I've read the page above and tried searching for this issue, but not gotten anywhere. What could be causing this?

I'm using MediaWiki 1.23.5 with the Vector skin. The search engine used is the vanilla search included with MediaWiki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default search of MediaWiki includes the Redirect pages, unhappily this can't be configured. The solution is: Use another search engine :) Wikimedia wikis using Lucene and currently being changed to Elasticsearch (using the CirrusSearch Extension). There redirect pages aren't visible as default.

There are also [some other full text search engines](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Fulltext_search_engines).

Comment: So is the quote from the documentation incorrect, then? I've noticed that the MediaWiki docs are quite messy, so this wouldn't surprise me!